# Why are my results displaying the way they are after I delete my typed input

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, input

I am trying to figure out why my list of results is looking the way it does after I clear my input field, It seems an extra list item with a comma as its value is being to my list of search results. When I clear my input field, I would like My search results to display the way they do when the user first opens the modal

```js
let results = document.querySelector(".result-list")
let listItems = results.getElementsByTagName('li')

$('button').click(function() {
  $('#school-popup-modal').attr('style', 'display:flex')
  $('#select-buttons').attr('style', 'display:none')
})

$('#cancel-btn').click(function(e) {
  $('#school-popup-modal').attr('style', 'display:none')
  $('#select-buttons').attr('style', 'display:flex')
  $('li').attr('style', 'display:flex')
  $("#search-input").val("")
  $("#undo").attr('style', 'display:none')
})

let dummyData = [{
  name: 'gables',
  id: 111
}, {
  name: 'palmetto',
  id: 222
}, {
  name: 'southwest',
  id: 333
}, {
  name: 'killian',
  id: 444
}]

dummyData.forEach((school) => {
  let schoolName = school.name
  $('.result-list').append(`
  <ul><li id="list-item">${schoolName}</li><ul>
  
  `)
})

$('li').click(function(e) {
  let elem = e.target
  $("#undo").attr('style', 'display:inline')
  $("#search-input").val($(elem).text())
  $('li').attr('style', 'display:none')
  $('#school-popup-content').attr('style', 'padding-bottom:20px')
})

// $('#search-input').keyup(function(){
//   let schoolsArr = []
//   const searchString = $("#search-input").val().toLowerCase()
//   dummyData.forEach((school)=>{
// schoolsArr.push(school.name)
// })
//   for(let school of schoolsArr){
//    if(school.includes(searchString)){
//   results.innerHTML = `<ul><li>${school}</li></ul>`
//    }
//     else if(searchString === "")  {
//   console.log('empty')

//     }
//   }
// })

document.querySelector("#search-input").addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
  const filteredSchools = dummyData.filter((school) => {
    return school.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
  })
  console.log(filteredSchools)
  let filtered = filteredSchools.map((school) => {
    return `
<ul>
<li>${school.name}</li>
</ul>
`
  })
  results.innerHTML = filtered
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 230px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  padding: 16px 50px 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  min-width: 297px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: normal;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  -ms-transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  -o-transition: all ease-in-out .qs;
}

#popup-buttons {
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#cancel-btn {
  min-width: 217px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border: red;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

#cancel-btn: hover {
  color: #000;
}

#popup-btn {
  font-size: 10px;
  min-width: 67px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 180px;
}

#popup-btn a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
}

button:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: transparent;
}

#school-popup-modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100000;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#school-popup-content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 440px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

input {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 253px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

#search-results {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  width: 272px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

input span {}

input[value=undo] {
  color: grey;
  text-align: right;
}

#undo {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 10;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  right: 25px;
}

.fas fa-check {
  height: 5%;
}

#undo:hover {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transition: .2s
}

#span-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup-header {
  font-family: 'itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  align-items: left;
  color: #000000;
  margin-right: 120px;
}

#select-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 5%;
}

#select-buttons button {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="school-popup-modal">
  <div id="school-popup-content">
    <div class="popup-header">
      <span>Find your School</span>
    </div>
    <p>School</p>
    <form>
      <div id="span-container">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="search-input" placeholder='Start typing...' type="text">
        <span id="undo">undo
          <span style="font-size: 10px; color: green;">
            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="#search-results">
        <div class="result-list">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="popup-buttons">
      <button id="cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
      <button id="popup-btn">Start Testing</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="select-buttons">
  <button>Test for School</button>
  <button>Test for work</button>
</div>
```

---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  What are the steps one takes to demonstrate the error?  When you debug, where specifically do you find an operation which is producing an unexpected result?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: `filtered` is an array. `Array.prototype.toString` returns the values of each element as a string, separated by commas. When you run `results.innerHTML = filtered`, that runs `filtered.toString()` and assigns that value to `innerHTML`. Remove the `school` from the array if you want it gone, or check for `school.name.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Your are putting an array in your HTML.

Try delete the line `results.innerHTML = filtered` from your JavaScript, and add:

```
// clear the results
results.innerHTML = '';
// insert the filtered results
filtered.forEach((filteredSchool) => {
    results.innerHTML += filteredSchool;
});
```